# Getting a scope error in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, oop, codeblocks

This may or may not be an IDE-specific question.

So I made a project using Code::Blocks. In the project folder there's Main.cpp, Person.h, and Person.cpp:

```
// main.cpp
#include "Person.h"
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
    Person p = new Person(x, y, z);
}
```

I'm getting an error saying that Person and "p" were not declared in this scope. But I declared them in Person.h. I included the Person.h header file. So, the code that is there should be in Main, too, right?

Here are the contents of Person.h:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

class Person
{
     public: 
          Person();
          Person(int, int, int);
     private:
          int x, y, z;
};

#endif
```

Comment: can you show what's in `Person.h`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the constructor inside the class.

```
Person(int a, int b, int c)
{
  x=a;
  y=b;
  z=c;
}
```

And change

```
Person p = new Person(x, y, z);
```

to

```
Person p(x, y, z);  //if you just want to make an object p
```

or to

```
Person* p = new Person(x, y, z);  //if you want a pointer p to point to a Person object

//your code goes here

//But in this case, you will have to explicitly deallocate the space you've allocated for p
delete p;
```

Comment: No, change it to `Person p(x, y, z);`. And presumably, the constructor definition exists in Person.cpp, but it should use a constructor initializer list anyway.

Comment: @chris What's wrong with `Person* p = new Person(x, y, z);`? The OP wrote the question in this pattern and must have wanted `p` to be a `pointer`.

Comment: Because it's asking for a memory leak (notice there's no `delete` in the OP's code)? Looks to me like the OP came from Java and just wants to make an object.

Comment: I changed it to `Person* p = new Person(x, y, z)` and it works fine now. Probably a ton of memory leaks now, though, since I forgot to deallocate. `Person p(x, y, z)` works fine, too. I assume this version deallocates automatically when the program closes?

Comment: @CoffeeMaker Not when the program closes, but before when it's out of scope.

Comment: @CoffeeMaker Welcome to C++, Its time to take more responsibility for memory. All the memory you ask for, it is your (programmers) duty to return it explicitly.